# .NET In-Memory DLL and ASP.NET pages

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

We have a scenario in our applications where we need to compile code and load the DLL produced in-memory. Up to this part is a requirement from our infrastructure standpoint and we cannot change that.

There is no problem with compiling and loading the DLL in-memory. However, ASP.NET aspx pages fail to load since asp.net cannot find the in-memory references/types.

I only can think of two possible ways but not sure which one is the most practical way:

1. Find a way to compile and execute the aspx pages or ascx controls myself using a custom HTTP handler
2. Find a way to link the in-memory dll as reference to the page/ascx control at the time of execution.

I appreciate your insights...

Comment: Saying "in memory" you mean that dlls are loaded dynamically, using Reflection?

Comment: Did you check if you use the full name of assembly? It would be great if you'd give us the piece of the code to see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At a company I once worked at, we had a "plug and play" architecture that allowed us to add User Controls (ascx) to the project dynamically, without the need to recompile the site each time we added/modified a control.

The basic architecture included a DB table that held each dynamic control's name, dll location and ascx page. Each control was compiled into a separate dll and that dll and the ascx page were stored together in the file system. Each control also implemented an Interface that allowed us to load and render it into a page.

During each page's load, whenever we encountered the interface, we would dynamically load the control into the page using `LoadControl()`.

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes and no, LoadControl() loads the ascx into the current page control hierarchy, ASP.NET at this stage does not allow you to add extra references to the external in-memory DLLs.

I think in this case you need to think more in terms of providing multi-tenancy type of a service where there is no physical precompiled dll or ascx file. all these elements needs to be loaded for each tenant as a tenant requests to access the system.